# Quickblox: cannot get request parameters (or userid) for QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult with zero objects

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

Is there a way to find for which user OR which request parameters were used to fetch custom objects in case returning zero objects as a result in my *completedWithResult* callback?

Background:
I am fetching several custom objects at the same time (for different users) and actually for different custom classes as well. In case some user do not have any custom objects for this specific class, which is the correct/best way to confirm which user this request was made for.

In practice, is there a way to get request parameters out somehow from *QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult* paged object?

If I get object, it is easy to check this using *QBCOCustomObject.userID*. But for paged result this is not available and when trying to check

*QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult.request.parameters* seems to be (null) each time.

For the request, I use following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[getRequest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:QBID] forKey:@"user_id"];
[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"CLASSNAME" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self context:MYCONTEXT];
```

Using: Quickblox library for iOS (latest git commit: Wed Nov 27 18:52:20 2013 +0200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use MYCONTEXT parameter and pass to it your getRequest.
SDK hide request data from programmer. (QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult.request = nil) You receive only server response. May be later this will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @frankWhite for your comments. Too bad, this will cause extra work for me due to making asynchronous calls synchronous in order to match different custom objects (classes) for correct users in question when fetching data from the cloud.. Hopefully you would be able to bring this information (at least userid) through SDK soon. Thx!